# R - create random numbers

Tags: r, random

I have huge dataframe like this:

```
df <- read.table(text="
             id       date
1            1        2016-12-01 
2            2        2016-12-02 
3            4        2017-01-03 
4            6        2016-11-04 
5            7        2017-11-05 
6            9        2017-12-06", header=TRUE)
```

I generate randomly 1 or 0 for each id. I'm doing it with this code.

```
set.seed(5)

df %>%
  arrange(id) %>% 
  mutate(
    rn = runif(id),
    discount = if_else(rn < 0.5, 0, 1)
  )
```

It works perfectly until I add new rows to my dataframe. Then are my random numbers different.

But what I need is not just generate random number for each id, but that number has to remain same even if new rows are added.

That means:

```
             id       date           discount
1            1        2016-12-01            1
2            2        2016-12-02            0
3            4        2017-01-03            0
4            6        2016-11-04            1
5            7        2017-11-05            1
6            9        2017-12-06            1
```

When new rows are added

```
             id       date           discount
1            1        2016-12-01            1
2            2        2016-12-02            0
3            4        2017-01-03            0
4            6        2016-11-04            1
5            7        2017-11-05            1
6            9        2017-12-06            1
7            12       2017-12-06            0
8            13       2017-12-06            1
```

Comment: Can you show us how you added the rows to your dataframe?

Comment: Actually I do not add that rows, I'm getting that data from database. And they are added to db by users.

Comment: Are you aware of `sample` and `rbinom`? I also don't get why you are looping over the rows when you could just do `set.seed(1); df$discount <- sample(0:1, nrow(df), TRUE)` but that's probably related to your use of `runif(id)` instead of `runif(1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the same `seed` before the "new" `data.frame` "call":

```
set.seed(5) # first call
df %>%
  arrange(id) %>% 
  mutate(
    rn = runif(id),
    discount = if_else(rn < 0.5, 0, 1)
  ) 
#   id       date        rn discount
# 1  1 2016-12-01 0.2002145        0
# 2  2 2016-12-02 0.6852186        1
# 3  4 2017-01-03 0.9168758        1
# 4  6 2016-11-04 0.2843995        0
# 5  7 2017-11-05 0.1046501        0
# 6  9 2017-12-06 0.7010575        1


set.seed(5) # added two rows, reset the seed
df2 %>%
  arrange(id) %>% 
  mutate(
    rn = runif(id),
    discount = if_else(rn < 0.5, 0, 1)
  ) 
#   id       date        rn discount
# 1  1 2016-12-01 0.2002145        0
# 2  2 2016-12-02 0.6852186        1
# 3  4 2017-01-03 0.9168758        1
# 4  6 2016-11-04 0.2843995        0
# 5  7 2017-11-05 0.1046501        0
# 6  9 2017-12-06 0.7010575        1
# 7 12 2017-12-06 0.5279600        1
# 8 13 2017-12-06 0.8079352        1
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text="
             id       date
                 1            1        2016-12-01 
                 2            2        2016-12-02 
                 3            4        2017-01-03 
                 4            6        2016-11-04 
                 5            7        2017-11-05 
                 6            9        2017-12-06", header=TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(text="
             id       date
                 1            1        2016-12-01 
                 2            2        2016-12-02 
                 3            4        2017-01-03 
                 4            6        2016-11-04 
                 5            7        2017-11-05 
                 6            9        2017-12-06
                 7            12       2017-12-06
                 8            13       2017-12-06", header=TRUE)
```